# Regular expression wildcard

Tags: c#, regex, string, wildcard

I've just started using `Regular Expressions` and this is so overwhelming that even after reading documentation I can't seem to find where to start to help with my problem.

I have to a bunch of strings.

```
 "Project1 - Notepad"
 "Project2 - Notepad"
 "Project3 - Notepad"
 "Untitled - Notepad"
 "HeyHo - Notepad"
```

And I have a string containing a wild card.

```
"* - Notepad"
```

I would need that if I compare any of these strings with the one containing the wildcard it returns true. (With `Regex.IsMatch()` or something like that..)

I don't usually asks for answers like that but I just can't find what I need. Could someone just point me out in the right direction ?

Comment: Is the string you want to "compare with" going to be a static string, user-input, etc? In other words, will it always be `* - Notepad` (or similar), or can it be modified during runtime?

Comment: wildcard would be `.*` (`.` being anything and `*` being repeat zero or more times)

Comment: It's going to be user-inputed string. It could compare Project1 - Notepad with Project1 - Notepad. But the user would have the choice to include all the Notepad projects with a wildcard

Comment: Similar question is posted here. I hope it helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400844/validate-that-a-string-contain-some-exact-words-with-regex-c-sharp

Comment: Are you trying to match anything that ends in "- Notepad" ?

Comment: take the string containing `*`, and replace `*` with `.*`, then check matches.

Comment: @Babblo yes but it is variable. It could be anything that Ends with - Notepad or  Untitled {*} - Notepad... the user inputs the wildcard

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The wildcard `*` is equivalent to the Regex pattern `".*"` (greedy) or `".*?"` (not-greedy), so you'll want to perform a `string.Replace()`:

```
string pattern = Regex.Escape(inputPattern).Replace("\\*", ".*?");
```

Note the `Regex.Escape(inputPattern)` at the beginning. Since `inputPattern` may contain special characters used by Regex, you need to properly escape those characters. If you don't, your pattern would explode.

```
Regex.IsMatch(input, ".NET"); // may match ".NET", "aNET", "FNET", "7NET" and many more
```

As a result, the wildcard `*` is escaped to `\\*`, which is why we replace the escaped wildcard rather than just the wildcard itself.

---

#### To use the pattern

you can do either:

```
Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern);
```

or

```
var regex = new Regex(pattern);
regex.IsMatch(input);
```

---

#### Difference between greedy and not-greedy

The difference is in how much the pattern will try to match.

Consider the following string: `"hello (x+1)(x-1) world"`. You want to match the opening bracket `(` and the closing bracket `)` as well as anything in-between.

Greedy would match only `"(x+1)(x-1)"` and nothing else. It basically matches the longest substring it can find.

Not-greedy would match `"(x+1)"` and `"(x-1)"` and nothing else. In other words: the shortest substrings possible.

---

#### How to escape the wildcard character?

@MaximZabolotskikh asked about the possibility of escaping the wildcard character, so that `"Hello \* World"` would literally match `"Hello * World"`.

To do this would require multiple substitutions.

1. Escape the regex.
2. Substitute any occurrence of `\\\\` (double backslash) with the escape character `\x1b`. This allows us to identify backslashes that were in the original input.
3. Substitute any occurrence of `\x1b\x1b` with `\\\\`. This allows matching a literal `\` by using `\\`.
4. Use the negative lookbehind pattern `(?<!\x1b)\\\*` to substitute `*` with the wildcard pattern (either `.*` or `.*?`) but only if it isn't preceded by a backslash. This will insert the wildcard pattern in `"Hello * World"` and `"Hello \\* World"`, but not in `Hello \* World`. We need to match `\\\*` because `*` is changed to `\*` after escaping, so we're actually matching a literal `\` (using `\\`) and a literal `*` (using `\*`).
5. Any escaped `*` will now be `\x1b\\*`, which will eventually be substituted to `\\\\*`, but we actually want it to be `\\*` instead so we can match a literal `*` later on. Therefore, substitute `\x1b\\*` with `\\*`.
6. Finally, substitute all `\x1b` back to `\\`.

Here's an example (I am using `@""` here to avoid typing double backslashes):

```
string pattern = Regex.Escape(inputPattern);
pattern = pattern.Replace(@"\\", "\x1b");
pattern = pattern.Replace("\x1b\x1b", @"\\");
pattern = Regex.Replace(pattern, @"(?<!\x1b)\\\*", ".*?");
pattern = pattern.Replace("\x1b\\*", @"\*");
pattern = pattern.Replace('\x1b', '\\');
```

Comment: So in this case string pattern would be * - Notepad ?

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk Assuming `inputPattern` is "* - Notepad", `string pattern` will be ".*? - Notepad". Keep in mind though, that if `myString` contains other special characters recognized by Regex, such as `. [ ( ) ] \ * + ?` your pattern will be quite messed up.

Comment: What if I **had** to use these characters like "?" or "." is there a way around ?

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk Yes, there is. Just read the part below "**Edit:**". Basically, all you'll have to do is find all these characters and place a single `\ ` in front of those characters, so `\ ` becomes `\\ ` or `.` becomes `\.` or `?` becomes `\?` etc.

Comment: didn't see that part. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: in this case, what is: "inputPattern"?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon. It's the original pattern: `"* - Notepad"`. In regex, the asterisk `*` matches the previous character 0 or more times, so `"hell*world"` could match `"helworld"`, `"hellworld"`, `"helllworld"`, `"hellllworld"`, etc. If you want to match `"helloworld"` or `"hello world"` or similar instead, you need to replace the `*` in the original pattern (inputPattern) with `.*` or `.*?`

Comment: Use `string pattern = Regex.Escape(inputPattern).Replace("*", ".*?");`. Otherwise if the pattern allready contains some regex special characters (dot for example), then the result will not be valid.

Comment: @Mahmoodvcs. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Nolonar Thank you too. You edit made me aware of a mistake that I was making.

Comment: What if my initial pattern is "value with \\*"? I.e. I want * to be a literal character? Than after escaping I have "value\\ with\\\\\\\*" and after replacing "^value\\ with\\\\.*$", which is wrong.

Comment: @MaximZabolotskikh, thank you for pointing this out. I've edited my answer to address this.

Comment: @Nolonar thank you for the wildcard solution, I will try this out. Meanwhile, I solved this with a direct string inspection https://stackoverflow.com/a/75220383/1105564

Answer (score 5):

I just wrote this quickly (based off of [Validate that a string contain some exact words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400844/validate-that-a-string-contain-some-exact-words))

```
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] inputs = 
        {
            "Project1 - Notepad", // True
            "Project2 - Notepad", // True
            "HeyHo - Notepad", // True
            "Nope - Won't work" // False
        };

        const string filterParam = "Notepad";
        var pattern = string.Format(@"^(?=.*\b - {0}\b).+$", filterParam);

        foreach (var input in inputs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern));
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Works great ! Only thing is since Notepad will be variable, using something like this : @"^(?=.*\b - " + variableContainingNotepad + "\b).+$" to change the word Notepad doesn't seem to work because of the "+" characters

Comment: use string.Format, I'll update my first post.

Answer (score 3):

You should do like this:

```
string myPattern = "* - Notepad";
foreach(string currentString in myListOfString)
    if(Regex.IsMatch(currentString, myPattern, RegexOptions.Singleline){
        Console.WriteLine("Found : "+currentString);
    }
}
```

By the way I saw you came from Montreal, additional french documentation + usefull tool:
http://www.olivettom.com/?p=84

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the pattern you want is the following:

```
/^.+-\s*Notepad$/
```

This pattern will match an entire string if it ends with "- Notepad".

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the answer. This is the exact regex needed without all these extra explanations