# Replace string in file c# with regex

Tags: c#, regex, file, replace, directory-structure

I cant make this code work with the regex *...
it appears that * isnt a regex for anything before page..
the txt file.pagdel contains  random  directory locations for the page and the page number like

H:\teste\pages\page_10

H:\teste\blankpages\page_11

i need to replace all directory structure in the bat file for an specific directory stored in a string variable called replace

example

H:\teste\pages\page_10      -- old pagdel

H:\teste\blankpages\page_11 -- old pagdel

H:\teste\newpages\page_10  -- new pagdel

H:\teste\newpages\page_11  -- new pagdel

```
File.WriteAllText("H:\\teste\\batch\\pagdel.bat", 
   Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText("H:\\teste\\batch\\pagdel.bat"), 
   "*page_", replace));
```

What im doing wrong.

Comment: I believe this stackoverflow question might help answer your question - [regular-expression-wildcard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275718/regular-expression-wildcard)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is to change regex:

from `"*page_"` to `".*page_"`

Hope it helps. Cheers.

EDIT:

```
replace = "H:\teste\newpages\page_";
```

Comment: when i use your syntax this error appearsAn unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: analysing "*.teste_" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing

Comment: @VictorLS Please let me know if You are using replace like in the edit part of the answer.

Comment: @VictorLS I just saw, that You misplaced `.` character. It should be like this: `".*teste_"` Please change that and it should work properly.