# c# wildcards not matching datatable column values

Tags: c#

I am having an issue trying to match data table column names with a string containing a wildcard.

I have a data table with various column names which includes a set named like follows: "PsA", "PsB", "PsC", ect.  I want to iterate through all the columns containing Ps in the title and use those titles to extract the data.

I currently have the following code which fails to return any matches.  I have substituted a straight value in the if statement ("PsA") as a test, which works fine; however, when I use the wildcard, I get no matches.  I have also tried Regex with no luck.

```
    private void dfaSection_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string psText = null;
        string colID = "Ps*";

        offBox.Text = "";                       //Clear textbox if a reselection occurs
        psBox.Text = "";                        //Clear textbox if a reselection occurs

        info.offTitle = dfaSection.Text;       //Set textbox from variable

        dt = opr.findOffByTitle(info);          //Get datatable from SQL database

        if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
             offBox.Text = dt.Rows[0][5].ToString();   //Set textbox from datatable

             foreach(DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)           //Loop through datatable columns
             {
                if (dc.ColumnName.ToString() == colID) //Check that column title matches test string     - Later addition--> && dt.Rows[0][dc].ToString() != null)
                {
                    psText = dt.Rows[0][dc].ToString() + "\n\n";    //Add data from matched column to string variable
                }
             }

             psBox.Text = psText;           //Set textbox from variable
        }

    }
```

Edit: Issue fixed using `.Contains(colID)` Column names now being matched, string are now not being loaded to the `psText` variable, but I'll spend some time with that and get it working.  Thanks Skaros Ilias.

Comment: `I have also tried Regex with no luck.` Please show us that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not so failiar with C, but `==` for sure is not the right method.
you need to use the `contains` method. As I said, I am not familiar with it, but the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3) have a good example of it.

```
String s = "This is a string.";
String sub1 = "this";
Console.WriteLine("Does '{0}' contain '{1}'?", s, sub1);
StringComparison comp = StringComparison.Ordinal;
Console.WriteLine("   {0:G}: {1}", comp, s.Contains(sub1, comp));
```

Answer (score 0):

As per this answer before : [Regular expression wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275718/regular-expression-wildcard)

And here is sample of code :

```
private static bool Match(string pattern, string stringToCheck) {
    var finalPattern = pattern.Replace("*", ".*?");
    Regex regex = new Regex(finalPattern);
    return regex.IsMatch(stringToCheck);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

take a breakpoint a check what is column name and `colID` at failure moment.How are you going to solve problems, when don't even know values?
Use `dc.ColumnName.ToString().StartsWith()`. `Contains()` is good only untill string endswith.

Comment: I have checked the values at run time.  I have also confirmed that a raw value works, which eliminates concern with values requiring trimming or similar. I have also test printed the column name values to ensure that they are being iterated through correctly.

Comment: ok, so what's `colID` value at failure? by the way. Remove wildcard from `colID` and do `.startswith`

Comment: colID is static and set to "Ps*".  I have tried your suggestion of removing the wildcard and using `StartsWith()`, however this has not worked either.

Comment: what's a `colID` value at failure? and what is error message?

Comment: There is no error/exception. The code runs, however does not match the values that are supposed to be matched (eg. `psText = dt.Rows[0][dc].ToString() + "\n\n";` is never run because the `if` statement is never satisfied, though I can find no reason for the values not to match. As I mentioned, I have replaced the `colID` in the `if` statement with a raw value (`"PsA"`) which then matches and runs `psText = dt.Rows[0][dc].ToString() + "\n\n";` as it is supposed too. When I then try to use a wildcard to match the column names, no matches are found.

Comment: I said remove wildcard from `colID`, but not to replace with something else. Do `string colID = "Ps";` instead of `string colID = "Ps*";` . And why do you still use wildcards as don't use regexes? If you make `colID` as PsA, then it matches only with PsA, but not PsB.